# How to convert VBA Range object into xlwings Range object

Tags: python, xlwings

In xlwings `xw.Range` object can access it's native VBA object with `.api`. Is there a simple way to invert this? For example:

```
wb = xw.Book()
rng = wb.sheets[0].range('A1:B1000')
rng.value = [[i % 2, i % 3] for i in range(1000)]
rng.api.AutoFilter(1, 0)  # filter for 0 in first column - effectively every second row is filtered out
visible_cells = rng.api.SpecialCells(12)  # 12 = xlCellTypeVisible
```

Is it possible to get the `visible_cells` as xw.Range object? For simple cases one can just use the `.Address` property and do: `wb.sheets[0].range(visible_cells.Address)`, but this property has 255-character limit (my example demonstrates this). Same limitation applies to `xw.Range` constructor (passing string over 255 characters raises error).

Two solutions that came to my mind are:

1. Iterate over `.Areas` to break the range into compact ranges. They will have "short" addresses, which then could be used, but I end up with a list of `xw.Range`s and I couldn't figure out the way to merge it into a single object (xlwings version of `Application.Union`). Even if possible, this could be very slow due to multiple `.api` calls.
2. Select the range and then read selection with xlwings. Quite simple to implement, but not very elegant as it has side effects (Selection changes, VBA events are triggered).

Any other ideas?